# TypeError: 'function' object has no attribute '__getitem__' from urls.py

Tags: python, django, migrate

When I try to migrate (manage.py migrate) in Django, I get the following error:

```
File "C:\Program Files\Python27\Scripts\Folder_Name\Folder_Name\urls.py", line 22, in <module>      
    url[(r'^$',ListView.as_view(queryset=ABC.objects.all(),template_name="Folder_Name/Folder_Name.html"))],
TypeError: 'function' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Below is what I have for Folder_Name/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView
from Folder_Name.models import ABC

urlpatterns = [

    url[(r'^$', ListView.as_view(queryset=IOC.objects.all(),template_name="Folder_Name/Folder_Name.html"))],

]
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

url patterns are not written like that.

Read more here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/urls/

Write it like this: (remove the list of `url[..]`)

```
urlpatterns = [

    url(r'^$', ListView.as_view(queryset=IOC.objects.all(),template_name="Folder_Name/Folder_Name.html")),

]
```

Comment: I made the changes and it worked! I'll also read the documentation you provided. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You have unnecessary square brackets around the arguments to `url`.

Comment: You are correct and that fixed the problem. Thank you!!